# How is this account able to consistently get her/his transactions with zero gas price mined?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, mining-pools

This account https://etherscan.io/address/0xbe7cd41e060cdb07c548d6c65f1d786e43f1c392 is able to keep sending transactions with zero gas price and they are mined. If I try to do the same, my transactions will get stuck forever.

Example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x13dd2fbbf9d403001623a6f90ab66ccd585832f14e38401806fa7d1e1f7f9013

How is this being done?

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of this: reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7lx1do/a_christmas_mystery_sweepers_and_zero_gas_price/

So possibly the address has a known miner friend who has agreed to mine his transactions for zero gas price for whatever reason. That's not so trivial to accomplish: the miner has to be able to finish mining the blocks, at least at some point in time.

Or then the transactions are simply added at a point when there is zero network congestion so miners have "nothing better to do" than to include zero gas price transactions.

Comment: Your answer reminds me of a question I asked here a while ago, about [why not mine my own transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/51517). The question itself might be slightly ill-phrased because I had less knowledge at the time, but regardless of that, the answer I was given sounds more or less like what you're suggesting. And like you said, it is not that trivial to accomplish, so I wonder how come this account has so many such transactions.